# Bootstrap floating navbar and alignment of anchors

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, anchor

I have what seems to be a common problem. I have a bootstrap navbar which floats at the top of the screen.

However:

- The top 50px of the page is covered by the navbar - but I can fix that with `body {  padding-top: 70px;}`
- When I try and navigate to `mypage.html#foo` the browser aligns the anchor to the `top` of the page, cutting off the top 50px. I can fix that with a script that uses `window.scrollTo`, but it's a bit hacky
- When I do the same by clicking within my page, the same thing happens and the `onload` handler isn't called.

Is there a simple solution to this? I could rewrite the click handler on every link, but that just seems horrible. Can I hook onto some `onnavigate` event?

This seems like a hugely common problem with the floating navbar so is there a more simple solution?

Posting code as requested:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="navbar-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Hello</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
  <h1><a name="1"></a>1</h1>
  <h1><a name="2"></a>2</h1>
  <h1><a name="3"></a>3</h1>
  <h1><a name="4"></a>4</h1>
  <h1><a name="5"></a>5</h1>
  <h1><a name="6"></a>6</h1>
  <h1><a name="7"></a>7</h1>
  <h1><a name="8"></a>8</h1>
  <h1><a name="9"></a>9</h1>
  <p><a href="#2">Go to 2</a></p>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Problems with it are:

- '1' is cut off the top (easy fix)
- If you go to `test.html#2`, '2' is cut off the top
- If you Click the 'go to 2' link, '2' is still cut off the top

It'd be nice if there were one simple thing that solved all 3 of these issues - all I can find at the moment are 3 separate hacks :)

Comment: do you have any code ? we can see what your doing at least then

Comment: Updated question with example code

Comment: Have you tried creating a div to hold your content, and having a padding top on the div?

Comment: The content div would have to be full-height with a scrollbar. I guess in that case why use a floating navbar at all? Is a floating navbar basically useless if you want to use anchors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved this by:

- Using a non-fixed navbar
- Creating a scrollable div that filled the whole screen apart from the top 50px and putting everything in that.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="navbar-wrapper">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Hello</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="position:absolute;top:50px;bottom:0px;left:0px;right:0px;overflow:auto">
  <div class="container">
  <h1><a name="1"></a>1</h1>
  <h1><a name="2"></a>2</h1>
  <h1><a name="3"></a>3</h1>
  <h1><a name="4"></a>4</h1>
  <h1><a name="5"></a>5</h1>
  <h1><a name="6"></a>6</h1>
  <h1><a name="7"></a>7</h1>
  <h1><a name="8"></a>8</h1>
  <h1><a name="9"></a>9</h1>
  <p><a href="#2">Go to 2</a></p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It still feels like there should be a better way of making a fixed navbar work, but hey.